# open new console and print string to that from python script

Tags: python, stdin

I have program which is open in command line and accept some argument for start work but also after start ask a question and wait for answer from standard input (stdin) somthing like this :

```
app.exe -start -silent
>Enter your code : (wait here for stdin)
after answer continue to working ...
```

Now i want to run that automatically from python means start program with arguments and then print my answer to that

I want to know how can i do this work in python ?

this is my code :

```
    p = subprocess.Popen('"C:\app.exe" -start -silent',
 stdin=subprocess.PIPE, universal_newlines=True, shell=True)    
    grep_stdout = p.communicate(input='my_input_string')[0]
```

but this code not work ! and i got error for input ! `ReadConsole() failed: The handle is invalid.`

can i do this work in python for open new process and print some string to that for input ? or anyone have any better solution or any sample or anything else ?

kind regards

Comment: where are you piping stdout?

Comment: what is need for stdout ?

Comment: what do you think will be in `p.communicate(input='my_input_string')[0]`? have you tried passing a list of individual args without shell=True?

Comment: yes i tried and ,same result !

Comment: does `subprocess.Popen('C:\app.exe -start -silent',
 stdin=subprocess.PIPE, universal_newlines=True, shell=True)` work?

Comment: On another note you may find winexpect useful https://pypi.python.org/pypi/winpexpect, also what is `app.exe`?

Comment: @Padraic Cunningham : Is it important what is `app.exe` ? I think no ! because i want to print/send/insert string to the `stdin` console and that's can be any command line application which need for `stdin`

Comment: It is important if  `subprocess.Popen('C:\app.exe -start -silent', stdin=subprocess.PIPE, universal_newlines=True, shell=True)` does not work

Comment: @PadraicCunningham when i  use from  `stdin=subprocess.PIPE` app.exe is carshed and don't run correctly ! but if i don't use that's work correctly ! and `app.exe` is a `openconnect` and i want to send password to that, now have any solution ?